# J2EE web application with restful session management

Tags: spring-mvc, jersey

I am refactoring a web application based on spring mvc by modifying some of the JSP pages to use restful calls.  I am planning to use Jersey with Spring for Restful API development.  I wonder whether the SecurityContext of jersey can access the session variables and JSESSIONID set by the spring mvc application.

Comment: `JSESSIONID` and RESTful do not match...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a httprequest object you can get the associated session.
As you are using Jersey for the REST services, You can use e.g.

```
@Context HttpServletRequest request
```